# Microscopic model of complex refractive index

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, refraction

In my Electromagnetic Optics class, we tried to reconcile the microscopic (optical) properties of matter with its macroscopic counterparts, and one of the most challenging properties is the (complex) refractive index, $n_c=n+i\kappa$, where $n$ is the refractive index and $\kappa$ the material's absorbance.

After all the approximations and calculations being done, we've reached the conclusion that, for those materials with no bound charges or whose free charges' behaviour is much more significant than that of its bound charges (that is, conductors), the complex refractive index is given by:

$$n_c = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\omega_p}{\omega}\right)^2}$$

where $\omega_p$ is the material's plasma frequency, and $\omega$ is the incident wave's frequency. My concern is this model does not allow for conductos to have nonzero $n$ and $\kappa$ simultaneously. I've graphed both of these magnitudes (using mock values) with respect to frequency so that my point is completely clear:

[image: Complex refractive index of a conductor as a function of the frequency]

As you can see, either $n$ or $\kappa$ is zero when the other one isn't. Can't we build a conducting material whch as $n,\kappa\neq0$ simultaneously? I'm assuming the problem I have presented arises from the fact that I'm not considering any dielectric behaviour whatsoever, so the material is exclusively composed of free charges, and for $n,\kappa$ to be nonzero at the same time we should have a real conductor, not an ideal one as the one I'm modeling.

Still, a doubt remains: if, for frequencies lower than $\omega_p$ we have $n=0$, then is the wave's phase velocity infinite in an ideal conductor? Because:

$$v_p = \frac{\omega}{k} = \frac{\omega}{nk_0}\to \infty$$

where $k$,$k_0$ are the magnitudes of the wavevector in the conductor and in vacuum, respectively. In order to state $k=nk_0$, I have assumed the conductor is an absorbent material (which is true, since $\kappa \neq0$) and $\vec{k}$ is parallel to the attenuation vector, $a$.